# how to save imported excel in datagridview to database C#

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

how to save imported data from excel in datagridview to database in C#
I have saved records and exported to excel sheet, it exported along with data ID, now I have re-imported back to datagridview from excel. now I want to save data to database.

[image]

**Important to know:**

Database name "Records.sdf" using SQL Compact 3.5
DataGridViewName is RecordsDataGridView.

I'm using following code but it's not working.

```
public void SaveData()
    {
        // Save the data.

        SqlCeConnection conn =
                new SqlCeConnection(
                   @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Records.sdf;Persist Security Info=False");

        SqlCeCommand com;
        string str;
        conn.Open();
        for (int index = 0; index < RecordsDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; index++)
        {
            str = @"Insert Into OutgoingChequeRecords(ID,BankName,Date,AccountNo, Chequebook, ChequeNo, Payee, Amount, Remarks) Values(" + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + ", '" + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "'," + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "," + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + "," + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[4].Value.ToString() + "," + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[5].Value.ToString() + "," + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[6].Value.ToString() + "," + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[7].Value.ToString() + "," + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[8].Value.ToString() + ")";
            com = new SqlCeCommand(str, conn);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

**ERROR RECEIVING**
**Column Name not Valid, column name = Cash**

Comment: Missing ' for values in some columns! You must wrap value between ' for Payee (col index 6, and also for other text columns)

Comment: please help date is saving as 0, column 2

Comment: Every value must have format. Use Parameters! Insert into table(column) values (@value) and then set parameter.I can't know the format of your date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query string

```
 str = @"Insert Into OutgoingChequeRecords(ID,BankName,Date,AccountNo, Chequebook, ChequeNo, Payee, Amount, Remarks) Values(" + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + ",'"+ RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "'," + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + ",'" + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + "','" + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[4].Value.ToString() + "','" + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[5].Value.ToString() + "','" + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[6].Value.ToString() + "','" + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[7].Value.ToString() + "','" + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[8].Value.ToString() + "')";
```

Comment: Worked but only 1 row got saved.
3rd row got saved, first two didn't and date is coming as 0.

Comment: Fixed it by keeping index to 0 and RecordsDataGridView.Rows.Count -1 to RecordsDataGridView.Rows.Count

Comment: please help date is saving as 0, column 2

Comment: Column 2, is't date type in datebase?
Try replace   ,'" + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "',

Comment: OR
 ,'" + Convert.ToDateTime(RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+ "',

Comment: yes fixed it basically, this is not the correct way to insert data, each data should be added with parameters, when I added each data with parameter I took the date data, converted into date then added into database that worked.

Comment: Current way, use stored procedure and add paramenters

Answer (score 1):

You should pass varchar field enclosed with single quote.

```
 var str = @"Insert Into OutgoingChequeRecords(ID,BankName,Date,AccountNo, Chequebook, ChequeNo, Payee, Amount, Remarks) Values("
                       + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + ", '"
                       + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "',"
                       + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + ","
                       + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + ","
                       + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[4].Value.ToString() + ","
                       + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[5].Value.ToString() + ","
                       + "'" + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[6].Value.ToString() + "'" + ","
                       + RecordsDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[7].Value.ToString() + ","
                       + "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[8].Value.ToString() + "'" + ")";
```

Comment: please help date is saving as 0, column 2

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.

Here is one method.

```
private void save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sAdapter.Update(sTable);
    dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
    save_btn.Enabled = false;
    new_btn.Enabled = true;
    delete_btn.Enabled = true;
}
```

http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-database-operations.htm

You can do this as well.

```
string StrQuery;
try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
        {
            comm.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            for(int i=0; i< dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++)
            {
                StrQuery= @"INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (" 
                    + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Text+", " 
                    + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Text+");";
                comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Something like this will work too.

```
private void buttonSave_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) // save to invoice
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
    string SqlCmdText = "INSERT INTO invoice (p_code, p_name, p_category, p_price) " +
                                  VALUES (@code, @name, @category, @price)";
    SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(SqlCmdText, con);
    con.Open();
    foreach (DataRow row in MyTable.Rows)
    {
        sc.Parameters.Clear();
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", row["p_code"]);
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", row["p_name"]);
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", row["p_category"]);
        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", row["p_price"]);
        sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    con.Close();
}
```